# Guillemin's Differential Topology - Prove S1 is not simply connected

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

It's problem 2.4.7 of Guillemin's Differential Topology. The problem asked me to prove $S^1$ is not simply connected, and it has a hint: consider the identity map. But I don't know the correlation between simply connected and intersection mod 2, which is the topic of this section.

Anyone knows how to approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since the circle is connected, all the constant maps $S^1 \to S^1$ are homotopic. Also, their graphs are clearly transverse to the diagonal, intersecting it in exactly one place (picture a horizontal line crossing a diagonal line).

On the other hand,  the graph of the identity map $\varphi : S^1 \to S^1$ is not transverse to the diagonal. In fact, the graph *equals* the diagonal! However, it is not difficult to see how to homotope the map to make it transverse. Let $\varphi_t(x)=x+t$ (viewing the circle as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$). For any small positive $t$, the graph of $\varphi_t$ is even disjoint to the diagonal and, in particular, transverse to it. So, what is the mod 2 intersection number of the identity?

Comment: Why does the image of identity map equal the diagonal? Isn't it the circle itself?

Comment: The graph of a function $f : X \to Y$ is the subset $\{ (x,f(x)) : x \in X\}$ of $X \times Y$. So, in the case of a function $X \to X$, the graph sits in $X \times X$.

Answer (score 1):

What is $\deg_2(\text{id})$? But mod-2 degree of a nullhomotopic map is $0$, and homotopic maps have the same mod-2 degree.