# Proving $S^1$ is not simply connected without the fundamental group machinery

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I am working on my undergrad thesis, which is about the Hopf-fibration of $S^3$. One of the key properties I want to show is that it can't be trivial. Usually people argue this using the fundamental group, and I understand these proofs.

However, given the space constraints and the other things I want to include, I feel it would not be best to introduce the whole fundamental group machinery just to prove this point. The fundamental group wasn't introduced in any of my lectures, but I do have "access" to homotopy theory.

EDIT: In particular, the sources I've found define simple connectedness **in terms of the fundamental group**. The definition I would like to use is that closed curves are null-homotopic/any two paths from $a$ to $b$ are homotopic.

In particular, it seems to be entirely sufficient to find some counterexample to show that $S^1$ can't be simply connected. $S^3$ is easily shown to be simply connected, so this would imply $S^3\not\sim S^2\times S^1$, which is exactly what is needed.

Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001521/guillemins-differential-topology-prove-s1-is-not-simply-connected), it seems possible to show that $S^1$ can't be simply connected using differential topology tools. However, this question is very specific to this textbook, which I don't have, so I can't really follow the reasoning.

Alternatively, is it perhaps possible to formalize the rubber-band analogy for $S^1$ not being simply connected? One counterexample is all that is needed...

Comment: You cannot beat something with nothing, you have to tell us what topological tools you know. The "rubber-band analogy" is only meant to provide some intuition, it cannot be used to prove anything.

Comment: To even define the notion of simply connected requires some amount of homotopy theory developed. Honestly, your best bet is to just not prove it in the paper and ask your advisor if you can just cite it as well-known, since it is.

Comment: You might be able to use complex analysis. If $S^1$ were simply connected the so would be $\mathbb C\setminus 0$ and a homotopy between two curves gives equal integrals. Then $$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{dz}{z}=0$$ for all loops $\Gamma.$ But there, $\Gamma$ tends to be over "nice" curves.

Comment: There is another option, like this. First, *read and understand* the usual proof of the fact that $S^1$ is simply connected. Then, for your undergrad thesis, write out a bare-bones proof that introduces no machinery except that which is absolutely needed for the proof of this one fact.

Comment: You can use covering spaces, I don't know if that is less machinery, but you could just develop the needed properties for the one covering space you require.

Comment: You should explicitly write down the definition of "simply connected" which you want to use.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm not exactly sure how to answer that, we mostly showed properties like total curvature which are invariant under homotopy.

Comment: Do you know — or can you prove — that in a simply connected manifold every closed $1$-form is exact?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see how this would create the desired contradiction, but I don't have this result. Does this proof look valid to you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007331/proof-that-closed-forms-are-exact-using-stokes-theorem

Comment: Sorry, my comment was mistyped, it was missing an important "not". So I'll retype it correctly: "There is another option, like this. First, read and understand the usual proof of the fact that $S^1$ is **not** simply connected. Then, for your undergrad thesis, write out a bare-bones proof that introduces no machinery except that which is absolutely needed for the proof of this one fact."

Comment: Just as Paul said above, the first step for us to answer your question is to know what is your definition of simply connectedness. If you say you don't want to talk about the fundamental group then it's pretty hard to guess what you've got in mind.

Comment: @LeeMosher could you tell me where to find this usual proof? I have been looking all day...

Comment: The isomorphism $\pi_1(S^1) \approx \mathbb Z$ is the first nontrivial example of fundamental group worked out in Munkres "Topology". You'll also need the implication "simply connected implies trivial fundamental group" but, as suggested by @PaulFrost, you'll need to be explicit regarding [which definition of simple connectivity you are starting with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space#Definition_and_equivalent_formulations).

Comment: @RubenKruepper Pretty much every algebraic topology textbook will contain a proof of this result.

Comment: Some years ago, I repeatedly taught a one-quarter undergraduate topology course. It was too short to include the fundamental group, but it always bugged me that we couldn't even get to coffee cups & donuts & balls, because those are the first things anyone hears about when they're trying to understand what topology is. So I worked out a way to treat simple connectedness, and prove that $S^1$ is not simply connected, without introducing the fundamental group. You can see the notes I prepared for the course [here](http://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Courses/441-2012/handouts.html).

Comment: @JackLee, this is absolutely perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not really versed in the history of topology, but I believe that in the old days simple connectedness was defined as getting disconnected after a suitable connected codimension 1 subvariety is removed (or some more precise definition of this idea).

For instance the sphere $S^2$ is simply connected because removing in fact any closed curve on it disconnects it.

From this point of view $S^1$ is not simply connected because removing a point does not discnnect it.